# How to achieve automatically-centered overstruck characters in html/css?

Tags: html, css

I need to do overstruck characters for things that Unicode can't represent (like p overst. with w)
I generally do this:

```
<span style="letter-spacing:-Xpt">pw</span>&nbsp;
```

But when you manually adjust the `letter-spacing` value over and over again for different characters, it gets pretty tedious.
Is there any way to automatically adjust the second character to be over the first character, in the center, every single time?
And no, I can't use a monospace font.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "p over w", is this a special charater not already covered by unicode? Like ㎺ https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+33BA

Comment: @Harrison p overstruck with w

Comment: Well that's precisely my confusion, unicode already covers these sorts of things if you want a specific character. What other overstruck symbols are you having issues with? It seems like the underlying issue could be the font being used. Many fonts won't have styles for these sorts of characters since they lie outside the basic Latin alphanumeric keyboard. e.g. "㎺" is not the same a "pW" even though it "looks the same"

Comment: I think the hint is in the _"like on a typewriter"_. So this is supposed to simulate typing errors made on a typewriter. Now old typewriters often used a monospaced font, so now I start to doubt this.

Comment: For a non-mono spaced font and a general solution we need to define what is meant by ‘centered’ and also what is the width of the resulting ‘character’ to be? Is it the natural width of the widest of the two characters?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i added that to distinguish it from "strikethrough"

Comment: @AHaworth the natural width of the widest of  two characters

Comment: So you need to know the relative widths of each character. I guess you have to find out how to read the .tif (or whatever) file to extract that information.

Comment: How do you want screen readers to read this? ie is it important that both characters ae in the DOM?

Comment: What do you want to do with these "overstruck" characters?

Comment: @AHaworth not important

Comment: @MfyDev i need to document really old constructed languages

Comment: Is it OK to assume that you can know which is the wider of the two characters?

Comment: @AHaworth yes   ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this method you need to know in advance which is the wider of the two characters.

Put that character into a span.

Then put the other character as content of the before pseudo element, by picking it up from an attribute in the span, positioned absolutely relative to its owner span and centered using left 50% and then wiggling it back by half its own width using translate.

That way you don’t need to know the relative widths of individual characters in advance.

```css
.doubleup{
  position: relative;
  
}

.doubleup::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(otherch);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div><span class="doubleup" otherch="p" >w</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with is this:

```css
div {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.overstrike {
  letter-spacing: -1ch;
}

.overstrike::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: ' ';
  width: 1ch;
}
```

```html
<div>this <span class="overstrike">iw</span>s a te<span class="overstrike">ds</span>t text</div>
```

I use some special features of CSS like [the ch unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) and [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after).

Note that the order of overwriting is important: The widest letter should be the second character in the span.

Comment: Nice idea but sadly doesn’t seem to work if you have two characters of the same, narrowish, width. As a simple test try ii.

Answer (score 0):

First, look up your character on [Unicode Plus](https://unicodeplus.com/). If you can't find that character, it means it's not included in Unicode.

Then, if there's no Unicode character you need, try to find a SVG of the character somewhere on internet. You can then use the SVG in your HTML document:

```html
<img src="./path/to/image.svg" alt="put a simlar unicode character here" />
```

Comment: it doesn't exist. i already did that

Comment: @qazw What character are you looking for?

Answer (score -1):

To achieve automatically-centered overstruck characters in HTML/CSS without using a monospace font, you can utilize CSS pseudo-elements to handle the positioning. By using the :before pseudo-element, you can place the second character over the first one and then apply position: relative to the parent element to ensure proper positioning. Here's how you can do it:

```
<div class="overstrike">pw</div>
```

To use this method, set the second character as the data-second-char attribute for the .overstrike element dynamically. You can achieve this using JavaScript or a server-side script if you're generating content dynamically. For example, in JavaScript:

```
    <div class="overstrike" data-second-char="w">p</div>
    
    
    .overstrike {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .overstrike:before {
      content: attr(data-second-char);
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      letter-spacing: -Xpt; /* Adjust this value to control the distance between characters */
    }
```